# How do I remove everything from a string except what I want?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

Okay, so basically I want the user to be able to input something, like `"quote python syntax and semantics"`, remove the word `'quote'` and anything else (for example, the command could be, `'could you quote for me Python syntax and semantics'`) then format it in a way that I can pass it to the Wikipedia article URL (in this case 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics'), request it and scrape the element(s) I want.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of doing this:

```py
import re
msg = input() # Here give as input "quote python syntax and semantics"

repMsg = re.sub("quote", "", msg).strip() # Erase "quote" and space at the start
repMsg = re.sub(" ", "_", repMsg)         # Replace spaces with _
print(repMsg)                             # prints "python_syntax_and_semantics"
```

The [python regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is very handy for doing this sort of things. Note that you'll probably need to fine tune your code e.g. decide when to replace first occurrence vs replace all, at which point to strip white spaces etc.